# Why is it not sleeping for 3 seconds before it starts listening?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I'm trying to do:

1. perform a `TextToSpeech`
2. SpeechRecognizer starts listening as the user repeats the
   TextToSpeech'd word/phrases

But my problem is that, for example, if i were to say "example" via TextToSpeech, when the SpeechRecognizer starts listening, it also takes in the "example" from previous and adds onto the one that the user says. So at the end, i ended up "example example", which i didn't want.

Code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
    tts.speak(item, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    sr.startListening(srIntent);
}
```

Comment: because your sleep is in another thread

Comment: put outside sleep with Thread object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing two process in Two thread. You are creating Thread One and make it sleep for 3 seconds and `sr.startListening(srIntent);` start Intent in separate UI Thread. So it start Intent Immediately. Use both process in one Thread like i post it below

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
tts.speak(item, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    mSpeech.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
};
thread.start();
```

}

Create one Inner Handler class to perform UI operations

```
private Handler mSpeech=new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
         sr.startListening(srIntent);
    }
};
```

Comment: YES! This solution worked. But do you mind explaining to me the usage of Handler? I've never come across this term as i'm just a beginner. Much appreciated!

Comment: no need to use handler, just use `runOnUiThread(runnable)` -_-

Comment: No need to use `Thread`. Just use `handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed`.

Answer (score 0):

it must be within the `run()` body

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
    tts.speak(item, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           sr.startListening(srIntent);
        }
    };
    thread.start();

}
```

Comment: i tried this way and it automatically crashed after waiting 3 seconds.

Comment: it says: SpeechRecognizer should be used only from the application's main thread

Comment: @rx24race try my solution, you have to take handler to start speech recognition